# laravel login link with return back redirection

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, back

I create main menu with login link for quest users.

```
@if(Auth::guest())
  <li><a href="{{ URL::route('auth::login') }}">Login</a></li>
@endif
```

What is the best way to make back redirection after login?

Now I made the next crutch:

```
// menu.blade.php
@if(Auth::guest())
  <?php
    if (Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() != 'auth::login')
      Session::put('login_back_url', Request::url());
  ?>
  <li><a href="{{ URL::route('auth::login') }}">Login</a></li>
@endif

// AuthController.php
public function __construct()
{
  ...
  if (Session::has('login_back_url'))
    $this->redirectPath = Session::get('login_back_url');
  else
    $this->redirectPath = route('home');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
use Redirect;
Redirect::back();
```

Comment: If that is social login?